# Speed up game after every 50 points

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, 2d-games

I am making a 2D reaction game with sprite-kit and I am having the same problem again. I already asked this question once and had good answers and everything worked finde but now I am stuck again.

Like the title says I want to speed up my game every 50 points, but it just speeds up when I get the right point number like 50, 100, 150.. The problem is that I have combo points and its always some points more. For example from 48 to 51 points, so it never speeds up. How can I speed up the game even its some points more ? I mean from 50 to 100 one speed up and from 100 to 150 and so on. Here is my code so far:

```
if (points % 10 == 0) {

    if (readyToSpeed) {

        speed++;
        NSLog(@"speed up");
        readyToSpeed = NO;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help ! (code in objective-c please)

EDIT: Works perfectly using both answers combined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of incrementing your speed you could do it like so:

```
speed = baseSpeed + (points / 50);
```

Where baseSpeed is the speed at the start of the game.

Comment: how can I set a limitation to this ?

Comment: just do a condition afterwards, if speed > maxSpeed, speed = maxSpeed

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about the exact 50x multiple points, keep track of the current point "group" via modulo to derive your speed value

```
cur_speed = points - (points % 50);
```

e.g. if they're at 203 points, then cur_speed is 203-(203%50) -> 203-3 -> 200. If they suddenly jump to 308 pts because they hit an insane points combo, then the speed becomes 308-(308%50) -> 308-8 -> 300

Comment: that looks good, but where and how can I implement this ? Because i don't know how to make the if statement.

Comment: Wherever/whenever you need to update the speed, I suppose. If their speed is totally dependent on their score, then you calculate which 50x group they're in, and use that to update the speed. Either as @PaulDaPigeon did below (base speed + total increment), or keep a running count with current speed = previous speed + change in point group.

Answer (score 0):

if you want just between 50-100 and 100-150 do something like this:

```
If points >  50 && points < 100 {  
//speedup code
}else if points > 100 && points < 150 {
//speedup code
} //etc
```

Update: if you want this to be endless do this:

```
var speednumber = points/50
speednumber = speednumber-decimal   //some code to cut of the decimals
setSpeedTo(speednumber+1) //you got to make a function for this
```

setSpeedTo(1) will be normal
2 will be from 50-100
3  100-150
Etc.